# Why geolocation queries not work in Google App Engine SDK 1.8.1?

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-search

Why this query not work in SDK console on - I want to find at least one place?

I opened SDK console and enter following queries without any results.

distance(geoLocation , geopoint(52.23261180, 21.02342870)) < 400000

distance(geoLocation , geopoint(52.23261180, 21.02342870)) > 0

Do you have any idea?

I was excluded following causes:

1. Data exist.
2. Field with location is named geoLocation.
3. Field contains some data search.GeoPoint(latitude=52.218052099999987, longitude=21.0046356).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe geosearch works in the dev app server yet; try with your deployed app.

Comment: Yeah it works only on production server - very bad since I can not test or debug code - everything need logging assertion and so on - time consuming. Whatever it is better than nothing :)

Comment: Here's the most relevant looking issue: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7769 It's with a Python title but Java comments too.